Why is a circling only approach published at this airport, Naples municipal, KAPF?
KAPF has GPS-A and GPS-B approaches, and the final approach course is exactly aligned to the runway heading.

For runway 32, GPS-A approach’s final approach course is 317°, and the runway heading is also 317°.

GPS-B approach has same heading as runway 14.


E.g. approach for RWY 14:

See also available procedures and airport diagram.
It looks normal straight in approach. But they only has circling approach on the procedure chart. Are there any valid reason for not publishing straight in?

And an educated guess is because it only has circling minimums applicable, as opposed to straight in minimums.

The answer is detailed in The Power of Paint. Just paraphrasing (here for RWY 32, but the same applies to RWY 14):
Conditions to be an instrument straight-in

There are three conditions stated in the FAA Instrument Procedures Handbook (FAA-H-8038-16B) preventing straight-in minimums:


The final approach course alignment with the runway centerline exceeds 30 degrees, which isn’t the case here.

The descent gradient is greater than 400 feet/NM from the FAF to the threshold crossing height (TCH). The actual descent gradient here is 316 feet/NM.

A runway is not clearly defined on the airfield.


The third condition is met.

Runway 32 does not have instrument-runway markings; i.e. lacks the paint to make the runway clearly defined.

Clear definition of a runway
Specifications from AC 150/5340-1M:

From Bing Maps, corresponding standard markings at Chicago O'Hare:

KAPF RWY 32 doesn't meet this standard. From Bing Maps:

The runway designator and the centerline markings are valid, but the threshold comb and the touchdown zone markings are missing. Straight-in minimums cannot be determined, only circling minimums can appear on the procedure and, since the runway is not properly identified:

Approaches that do not have straight-in landing minimums
are identified by the type of approach followed by a letter.


The perfect user to answer this question!
